# Git merge into past commit

Tags: git, merge, version-control

We have a git history that looks like this. This is already pushed to remote but can I possibly merge the branches at certain commits?  Or am I limited to only merging the commit at the very top?
[image: Ruined git history]

where blue is origin/master and magenta is a feature branch that has been physically copied into the master branch.

Comment: How do you want to merge the two branches? merge the feature branch into a past commit from master branch or the opposite?

Comment: Yeahp feature into one of the existing master commits

Comment: if you merge, you get a merge commit that is above both its children. You can merge anything with anything, but in your case the result would not be on master anymore. However, it is possible to rebase master onto that commit, but that would require push --force, which changes history and can cause lots of trouble. If that's what you want to do, let me know I'll take more time to detail how this weekend

Comment: I still want to maintain the master and feature's history though. What would it look like if I did that? Wouldn't the existing history still be there?

Comment: @JarrenOng I added an answer for merge feature branch into an old commit on master branch, you can have a try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume the commit history as below, and you want to merge `feature` branch into commit `B`:

```
...---A---B---C---D  master

...---E---F---G---H  feature
```

Then you can execute below commands:

```
git checkout commitB
git merge feature --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Assume the merge commit id commit `M` as below commit history:

```
                  C---D  master
                 /
      ...---A---B---M 
                   /
...---E---F---G---H  feature
```

Then you can execute the commands:

```
git rebase --onto commitM commitB master
git push origin master -f
```

And now the commit history will be:

```
      ...---A---B---M---C'---D'  master 
                   /
...---E---F---G---H  feature
```

Comment: Problem with this is that the branches are on unrelated histories. I can't do a merge.

I have to do a `git pull origin/master --allow-unrelated-histories` which puts me at the top.

Should I create a branch at commitB and push that? Then I think I can do `--allow-unrelated-histories` and then `git merge feature` ?

Comment: Yes, use `git merge feature --allow-unrelated-histories` instead.

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't know you could do that on merge. This works but I'm just having problems resolving conflicts. Thanks very much!!

Comment: To resolve merge conflicts, you can modify and save all the conflict files firstly, and then use `git add .` and `git commit` to finish the merge :)

Comment: hi, i know this is old but something here doesn't add up to me and i was wondering if you could explain.
right after performing the merge, isn't commitM the new child of commitB? and thus when performing the git rebase --onto line with commitB as the <oldparent> we are basiclly rebasing commitM on top of commitM? 
how does git know to treat commit C of master as the child of B when in deatched head state commit M is the child?

Answer (score 3):

Being in the master branch then
git merge "commit-id"
This should do it

Comment: I don't think this was exactly what the OP was looking for based on the comments, but I think it answers the (unclear) original question, and it answers my question.

Answer (score 3):

If possible, a merge between the two branch HEAD is preferable, as it will add a new commit (a merged commit) to the master branch, allowing for an easy (fast-forward) push.

Anything else might change the history, making you do a `git push --force` (which can be problematic if you have other collaborators using the repo)